# Migrating changes from a dev APEX app to production?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a production copy of an Apex app, and a copy on which I made changes and developed it into a newer version. Now that I am done developing and testing, is there an easy way to import my changes to the production version? Note that I cannot simply replace the production model with my new app. Do I have to make all those changes individually now on the production app?

Comment: What are your concerns about building over the production instance with your dev instance? Apex preserves user settings nicely (such as IR reports). We routinely build our production environment from SQL scripts created in Dev and managed in SVN. You just need to be careful to make **app** changes only in dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you replace the entire app?  Is it because you've made changes in the development environment that you don't want to go to production?  Is it because there have been other changes to different pages and components in prod since you made your changes?  Is it because there have been changes to the same pages and components in prod that you've changed in dev?

You can export individual pages and individual components at a very granular level in the APEX development environment.  There is documentation for [exporting individual components of an APEX application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11947/deploy.htm#autoId24) in the APEX Application Builder User's Guide for whatever version of APEX you're using.  Of course, that requires that you identify the pages and components you've changed.  The APEX Application Builder interface, though, will show you various reports of the last time pages or components were modified which should make that process simpler.